# Finding the row with shortest distance between two dataframe columns in Python

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Suppose I two dataframes as follows,

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1.5, 2.5], 'b': [0.25, 2.75], 'c': [1.25, 0.75], 'd': [1.5, 2.5],'e': [0.25, 2.75], 'f': [1.25, 0.75]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1.5, 2.5,3.5,4.5], 'b': [0.25, 1.5, 2.5, 2.75], 'c': [1.25, 0.75, 3.5, 4.5], 'd': [1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5],'e': [0.25, 2.75, 1.5, 3.5], 'f': [1.25, 0.75, 2.5, 4.5]})
```

I am trying to implement a function in which we would pass four parameters. First two would be two dataframes and third variable would be array of column names and fourth would be distance parameter.

For every row in df1, I want to find the distance of that row with all the rows of df2 for specific columns. After finding the distance, I want to find the minimum distance for that individual row among all and return the corresponding 'e' value of df2.

For eg, If I pass a and b columns, For each row of df1, I want to find distance between a and b for all the rows in df2 and find the minimum distance of all and get the corresponding 'e' value of df2.

For the first row of df1, distance calculated would be

```
((1.5,1.5), (0.25,0.25)) , ((1.5,2.5), (0.25,1.5)), ((1.5,3.5), (0.25,2.5)), ((1.5,4.5), (0.25,2.75)) , ((2.5,1.5), (2.75, 0.25)) , ((2.5,2.5), (2.75,1.5)), ((2.5,3.5), (2.75,2.5)), ((2.5,4.5), (2.75,2.75))
```

And find the minimum distance and corresponding 'e' value of df2 and store it in a variable.

The following is my trying,

```
def distance(x1, x2, L):
    dist = (np.sum((np.array(x1)-np.array(x2))**L))**(1/(float(L)))
    return dist

def shortdist(data1,data2,variables,L):
    variables.append('e')
    data1 = data1[variables]
    data2 = data2[variables]
    min_values=[]
    for index2, row2 in data2.iterrows():
        # print row2
        for index1, row1 in data1.iterrows():
            print distance(row2,row1,L)
            # print row1

    return min_values
```

Calling the function,

```
shortdist(df1, df2,['a','b'],2)
```

I am able to write the distance function and subset the required columns. But getting many errors after that.

Comment: What you can do is combine both dataframes rows into an array and then use any distance metrics to calculate your distance. `squareform(pdist(array of pairs here,(u,v: haversine(u,v))))`

Comment: What errors are you getting? I tried your code and it works (with Python 3).